# How do I run Oracle VM VirtualBox on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox, oracle

This might be a very silly question. But I was using ubuntu 11.04 and i upgraded to 13.04. I have installed oracle Virtual box successfully. But I cannot seems to find the application(oracle VM box) dashhome under applications?

How do i find the executable file that actually open the Virtual box? Will it not be displayed under Unity?

Comment: How did you install?

Comment: The start-up script is usually in /usr/bin which is in the standard path, so just type virtualbox in a terminal window and it will fire-up. The default installation path is /usr/lib/virtualbox

Comment: I just downloaded the virtualbox-4.2_4.2.18-88780~Ubuntu~raring_amd64.deb and installed using the usual command

Comment: Typing virtualbox did work.. is there any other way to run it other than using the command prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try to reinstall VMVB and see what happens...

1. Backup your existing VMs.
2. Remove the existing installation of VMVB.
3. Install VMVB again.

Try to check if these steps will fix the problem.

If they don't you can try to reset Unity. In this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html), you can find one way to do it.

Comment: It did not work :( however, it works when i type virtualbox on the command promt

Comment: so meaning your unity just doesn't show the virtual box but its there.. what are your intentions in runningg the vm? are you using it as a vortual server or just trying out other operating systems?

Comment: My intentions are to try out other opperating systems. for example if I want to use windows then i can use virtual box ect

Comment: Can you try to reset unity by following this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html)?

Comment: The solution to the problem (reset Unity) is not in the answer, but in the comments. The answer should not be accepted as it is. I'll edit it.